# Add external libraries or SDK in C++ Netbeans on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, exiv2

I am looking for a clear cut answer kind of new to c++ coming from a JAVA background where you just add the JAR file to your project. I am trying to build a project which examines metadata so I am using Exiv2

I want to add this to my project how do I do this? I am using Netbeans for my development environment and using Mac OS X would appreciate a answer so I can get the linking out of the way and fully understand it, thanks

README FILE

```
22Exiv2
*****

Welcome to Exiv2, a C++ library and a command line utility to read and
write Exif, IPTC and XMP image metadata. The homepage of Exiv2 is:

    http://www.exiv2.org/

See doc/ChangeLog for a list of recent changes to Exiv2.

Exiv2 API and tag reference documentation is at http://www.exiv2.org/doc
or you can build it and point your browser to doc/index.html.

For more information on XMP support in Exiv2, see doc/README-XMP.

Building and Installing
=======================

You can build the libraries in the following ways:

1 UNIX-like systems (including GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Cygwin, MinGW)
  - general notes follow
  - FAQ concerning Cygwin/MSYS and Mac OS X:
    http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/FAQ

2 Microsoft Visual C++
  - see msvc2003/ReadMe.txt      (32bit build           VC7.1/2003 2005,2008)
  - see msvc2005/ReadMe.txt      (32bit and 64bit build VC8/2005,  2008,2010,2012)

3 CMake (experimental support for cmake on all platforms)
  - see README-CMAKE for more information

To build a commercial version of the Exiv2 library, see also section
"Commercial version" at the end of this file.

On UNIX-like systems, use the GNU configure script. Run the following
commands from the top directory (containing this file) to configure,
build and install the library and utility:

    $ ./configure
    $ make
    $ sudo make install

If you downloaded the source code from the subversion repository, you
won't have a configure script. Run 'make config' to generate it and see
the section "Hacking" below.

The default install locations are /usr/local/lib for the library,
/usr/local/bin for the exiv2 utility and /usr/local/include/exiv2 for the
header files. Use the --prefix=directory option of the configure script to
change the default. Run './configure --help' to see a list of all options.

To uninstall Exiv2 from a UNIX-like system, run:

    $ make uninstall


Dependencies
============

The following libexiv2 features are enabled by default and may*)
require external libraries. They can be controlled through configure
options. See also './configure --help'.

Feature                     Package   Configure options
--------------------------  --------  ----------------------------
PNG image support           zlib      --without-zlib
                                      --with-zlib=DIR
Native language support     gettext   --disable-nls
Characterset conversions    libiconv  --without-libiconv-prefix
                                      --with-libiconv-prefix[=DIR]
XMP support                 expat     --disable-xmp
                                      --with-expat=DIR

zlib         http://zlib.net/
gettext  *)  http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/
libiconv *)  http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/
expat        http://expat.sourceforge.net/

*) Some systems have gettext and iconv in libc. The configure script
should detect this.

On Linux, it is usually best to install the dependencies through the
package management system of the distribution together with the
corresponding development packages (for the header files and static
libraries).

To build the sample programs in the samples/ directory ('make samples'),
you also need to have the pkg-config program.

To generate the documentation ('make doc'), you will further need
doxygen, graphviz, python and xsltproc.

pkg-config   http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/
doxygen      http://www.doxygen.org/
graphviz     http://www.graphviz.org/
python       http://www.python.org/
xsltproc     http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
md5sum       http://www.microbrew.org/tools/md5sha1sum/

Troubleshooting
===============

If you have problems building Exiv2 on UNIX-like systems, check the
generated config/config.mk and config/config.h files. You should *not*
need to modify any Makefile directly, in particular not src/Makefile!


Support
=======

All project resources are accessible from the project website at

    http://dev.exiv2.org/wiki/exiv2

Please send feedback or queries to the Exiv2 forum. For new bug reports
and feature requests, please open an issue.


Linking your own code with Exiv2
================================

A pkg-config .pc file is installed together with the library.
Application developers can use pkg-config(1) to obtain correct compile
and link time flags for the Exiv2 library. See samples/Makefile for an
example.

If you downloaded Exiv2 directly from the subversion repository, and
you want to build it using the GNU configure script, then you need to
have GNU Autoconf installed on your system and create the configure
script as the first step:

    $ make config

Then run the usual './configure; make; make install' commands.

Exiv2 uses GNU Libtool in order to build shared libraries on a variety
of systems. While this is very nice for making usable binaries, it can
be a pain when trying to debug a program. For that reason, compilation
of shared libraries can be turned off by specifying the
--disable-shared option to the configure script.

License
=======

Copyright (C) 2004-2015 Andreas Huggel <ahuggel@gmx.net>

Exiv2 is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free
Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
option) any later version.

Alternatively, Exiv2 is also available with a commercial license,
which allows it to be used in closed-source projects. Contact me for
more information.

Exiv2 is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License
for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, 5th Floor, Boston,
MA 02110-1301 USA.

Commercial version
==================

If you have a commercial license, you must disable NLS support and
the conversion of Nikon lens data to readable lens names to build a
commercial version of the Exiv2 library.

To do this on Windows, compile the library with the preprocessor
symbol EXV_COMMERCIAL_VERSION defined in:
   msvc2003\include\exv_msvc.h
or msvc2005\include\exv_msvc.h

On UNIX-like systems, run the configure
script with the options --enable-commercial --disable-nls
--disable-lensdata.

# That's all Folks
```

Comment: There is no clear cut answer, because C++ is cross-platform, whereas Java is always the same platform, i.e. there are always the same JVM instructions, unless you cope with JNI calls. That's why you can just slap a JAR file in your project (read: the IDE adds flags to the Java compiler to specify the path of the file). In C++, it's a bit more complex, because you need a prebuilt library for your platform, built with compiler flags that are compatible to how your application is built. Or you need to build the library yourself from source code, again compatible with your application.

Comment: In other words, C++ libraries usually have a readme file, install file or a build file you have to read to understand how to use the library in your specific compiler and IDE combo. Unfortunately there is no universal way of doing this in C++ as all libraries are done somewhat differently.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply guys I will get back to everyone

Comment: I included the README in my edit  but to be quite honest I don't work with these types of libraries and quite frankly have never done it before I'm so use to the connivence of the JAR but love c++ and its new imposed challenges its just frustrating to try and link libraries to get everything going, Can someone please explain to me as a beginner what I need to do to make this library work in Netbeans so I can continue to build projects in C++